# How to produce a random integer which excludes Keras input, without converting the input to a numpy array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After `model.train_on_batch` passes input and label to the Keras model, I want a random number to be generated which excludes the input integer that was passed to the model, without having to convert the number into a numpy array. Here's an example of what I'm talking about

```
#defining Keras model 
the_input = Input(shape=(1,))
the_random = #some function that gives a number between 1 and 100 excluding the input
.....#rest of model
.....
.....#rest of Keras setup
#Keras training, passing input and label to the model
model.train_on_batch( 7 , label)
```

So, `the_random` should be a random integer which excludes the number given in the input, in this case 7.

I know a work around would be to use `tf.keras.backend.eval(the_input )` to get the numpy version of the input, then used a function to get a random number, but I prefer not to make that conversion in order to speed up training.

If it makes a difference, the backend I'm using is Tensorflow

Comment: Does the function generating the random number have trainable parameters? If not, then why don't you pass the random number as another input to the model?

Comment: Good question, in my situation the other input will come from Tensorflow's dataset API object which will be shuffled when it passes input into the Keras architecture. And I need the random number to be different from the number passed by the dataset object.

Comment: Modify your input pipeline such that you create a different random number for each input.